# Find sqrt(i) and cube-root (i), giving where possible exact answer is in the form a+bi, where a and b are surds.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, trigonometry

Find sqrt(i) and cube-root (i), giving where possible exact answer is in the form a+bi, where a and b are surds.

I do know that the wording of the question is weird, but this is what the question is 1 to 1.

The working I did is as shown -

z=sqrt(i)

z^2=i

therfore there are two possible roots for i

z^2=0+i, and as z=(r)cis(angle in radians)

z^2=1cis0

z^2=1cis(0+2k(pi)), where k is the number of roots possible, in this case 2.

You guys might use a different method so I'll explain what we use here. when there are two roots, we substitute k for 0 and 1. for three, 0,1, and 2 so forth.

z=1cis((2k(pi))/2)

when k=0,
z=1cis(0/2)

z=1+0i. ---> not a surd, however?

when k=1,

z=1cis((2pi)/2)

z=-1+0i ----? once again, not a surd.

This is what the answers for the sqrt(i) are apparently.

(sqrt(2))/2 +(sqrt(2))i/2, and -(sqrt(2))/2 - (sqrt(2))i/2

For the cube root of i,

(sqrt(3))/2 + 1i/2, and -(sqrt(3))/2 +1i/2, and -i.

also, aren't a and b not always surds as asked in the question?
Thank you for your time. Helping me understand this answer would be great.

Comment: You wrote $i = 1\operatorname{cis} 0$, but probably you mean $i = 1\operatorname{cis} \frac{\pi}2$.

Comment: Please see [how to use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), the maths formatting that helps make your work look a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without resorting to De Moivre's theorem or the trigonometric/polar form of complex numbers.

$\sqrt{i}$ represents a (complex) number whose square equals $i$; that is to say, if $z = a + bi \in \mathbb C$ for a pair of real numbers $a, b$, then $z = \sqrt{i}$ implies $$z^2 = (a+bi)^2 = a^2 + 2abi + (bi)^2 = (a^2 - b^2) + 2ab i = i.  \tag{1}$$  Equating real and imaginary parts, this implies $$a^2 - b^2 = 0, \\ 2ab = 1. \tag{2}$$
The first equation implies either $a = b$ or $a = -b$.  In the first case, $a = b$, the second equation then gives
$2a^2 = 1$, or $a = \pm \sqrt{1/2}$, from which it follows that $$z = a + bi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} i,$$ or $$z = a + bi = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} i.$$

In the second case with $a = -b$, the second equation becomes $-2b^2 = 1$, but this has no real solution for $b$ (remember, $a$ and $b$ are real numbers).  So the second case is impossible and there are two unique solutions for $z$.  You can then check that $(\pm (1+i)/\sqrt{2})^2 = i$.

Next, consider how this method might be used to compute $i^{1/3}$.  This would mean solving for real $a, b$
$$(a+bi)^3 = i.$$  What is the system of equations that results from this condition?

---

If you know how to use the polar form of a complex number $$z = re^{i\theta} = r (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta),$$ and in particular De Moivre's theorem
$$z^n = r^n \cos n\theta + i \sin n \theta,$$  then the computation of the square and cube roots of $i$ should be straightforward; e.g., $i = e^{i \pi/2}$ hence $z^3 = i$ implies $$z = e^{i \pi/6 + 2\pi i k/3}, \quad k \in \{0, 1, 2\}.$$

Comment: Although I do understand this, the answer says sqrt of 2/2 + sqrt pf 2/2 instead of the answer you gave. Is it possible to obtain this specific answer? Also, I do appreciate you giving an answer without De Moivre's Theorem, however, the question came from a section of a book that uses De Moivre's Theorem and covers how to use it and etcetera.

Comment: @WooLuke $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.$$